# style.marginLeft doesn't work in wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I want to add margin-left for the object in wordpress theme using javascript.
First I add in function.php:

```
function loadingOwnScripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'own-scripts',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/own_scripts.js',
        array ('jquery'),
        null,
        'true'
    );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadingOwnScripts');
```

Then in the .js file:

```
var menuWidth = document.getElementById('main-navigation').offsetWidth;
if ( menuWidth > 0 ) {
    var marginL = (menuWidth * 0.353271028) + 'px';
    var navPointer = document.getElementById('nav-pointer');
    navPointer.style.marginLeft = marginL;
    alert(marginL);
};
```

And it doesn't work. I don't know why.
it doesn't work even if I put it:

```
navPointer.style.marginLeft = "500px";
```

Comment: is it going inside the if condition?

Comment: are you getting the alert() or does nothing happen? If nothing happens the if() statement is always returning false. Console.log menuWidth to make sure you are getting .offsetWidth() correctly.

Comment: add `console.log('ok')` before the `if` statement to check if your script is loaded correctly.

Comment: now alert doesn't work. but before navPointer.style.marginLeft = marginL; works.